# How to trace the path on a command

Tags: raspbian, filesystem

I'm trying to salvage some code on a project that was passed on to me, but I can't find the actual file for the code that I'm trying to find.  I have tried which, echo, rgrep, and gdb.  What other methods are there to find the path of a commands that can be called anywhere?

Comment: if you know a string specific to the file you could run strings command http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_strings.htm, or grep a directory for a regex match. It would also help if you provided a little more detail (how are you calling the program, what is the program etc.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a generic Linux/Unix question and is better answered on that StackExchange site.

Comment: I don't totally understand your question, but usually the $PATH variable shows locations searched when you type a command. Check it with `echo $PATH`. You seem be talking about code? Can you define a language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find a string in a file or a certain file name `grep` should work if you are using it in the LXTerminal shell. If you have no idea whatsoever of any folder it is in make root(`/`) the directory to start from. Lets say the name of your file is foo.txt.

You would issue the command, `grep / "*/foo.txt"`. Use the "*" character for any parts of this command you do not know. For example you could replace "txt" with "*" if you did not know the extension(if there was one). You can also search for a certain phrase with this format: `grep -ril "TEXT TO FIND" /path/to/search` using asteriks as needed.

If you issue the command improperly it will print a long line of folders and then say file not found at the end which might of been your problem. This is more of a Linux/Unix question and so if you leave Raspberry Pi out of your searches you might find more information. Here is an in depth [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/) on the command.